# Keyframe visible on timeline, but no keyframe markers in dope sheet

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

[image: keyframe markers gone]

While working on my third animation in Blender (a couple of fighter craft taking off from the launch platform), I wanted to smooth out the transition from VTOL to horizontal flight by slightly shifting the timing of a keyframe. I opened the dope sheet, thinking it would be an easy fix, but I found that the key frame markers are all gone, despite the keyframes still being there (see the timeline for proof of that). All I can see is a few bar graphs. Is there some weird setting I've accidentally enabled? Can I switch back to the normal visualization of keyframes that is easy to work with?

Comment: Make sure your object is selected.

Comment: The moving object is selected, otherwise the keyframes wouldn't show on the timeline. No markers appear no matter what object I select.

Comment: From what I can tell in your pic, the model you've selected is highlited ok in the DopeSheet, but you haven't expanded the little arrow at it's title strip. This should reveal it's keyframes. (The bar graphs are something I've not seen before)

Comment: Saving, exiting and restarting blender fixed the problem.  I still have no idea how I got the bar graphs in the first place, but at least they're gone now.